# Swagger UI Oauth2 callback sends code as query param instead of posting

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, openid-connect, auth0

I'm trying to use OIDC to protect a .NET 8 API. I've been basing my project on this article: https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet

So far, I can call the login endpoint, it correctly goes through the whole login procedure and I am able to call Authorized endpoints afterwards. Now I'm trying to set up Swagger UI so it effectively does the same.

**First issue:**

If I call the login endpoint via Swagger, it responds with [image: swagger response]

But I figured I didn't need to fix this here, because I can use the regular 'Authenticate' button on the UI instead, which leads me to

**Second issue:**

When I manually call the endpoints, the authentication callback is a POST, and everything works. When I log in through Swagger, everything works up to the callback, which is a GET with the code as a query param. I cannot find the setting I need to change to make Swagger trigger a POST instead.

Here is the relevant Swagger config:

```
internal static void Configure(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services, IWebHostEnvironment environment, string apiName)
{
    var authOptions = configuration.GetSection("Auth0").Get<OIDCOptions>();

    // Add Swagger options
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    { 
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = $"{apiName} - {environment.EnvironmentName}", Version = "v1" });

        var securityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Cookie,
            OpenIdConnectUrl = new Uri($"https://{authOptions.Domain}/.well-known/openid-configuration")
        };

        c.AddSecurityDefinition(
            "oauth2",
            securityDefinition);
    });
}

internal static void Configure(SwaggerUIOptions c, IConfiguration configuration, string apiName, string environmentName)
{
    var authOptions = configuration.GetSection("Auth0").Get<OIDCOptions>();

    c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", $"{apiName} - {environmentName}");
    c.InjectStylesheet("custom.css");
    c.EnableFilter();
    c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
    c.OAuthUsePkce();
    c.OAuthConfigObject.ClientId = authOptions.ClientId;
    c.OAuthConfigObject.ClientSecret = authOptions.ClientSecret;
    c.OAuthConfigObject.AppName = "Auth0";
    c.OAuth2RedirectUrl($"https://localhost:5001/callback");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, and the issue wasn't related to GET/POST at all. As far as I understand it, SwaggerUI creates a separate authentication middleware instead of using an existing one. Since I set the callback to the same path already used by a different auth setup, it didn't know what to do with the token coming in. Removing `c.OAuth2RedirectUrl($"https://localhost:5001/callback");` and adding the swaggerUI default callback path to the "allowed callback" list in my Auth0 app registration seems to have fixed the problem.